# What does Hartshorne mean here in Proposition 2.3?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was re-reading Hartshorne, proposition 2.3 on page 73. He says:

> Now for any open set $V\subset \operatorname{Spec}A$ we obtain a homomorphism of rings $$f^{\sharp}:\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(V)\to \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(f^{-1}(V))$$ by the definition of $\mathcal O$, composing with the maps $f$ and $\varphi_p$. This gives the morphism of sheaves $f^{\sharp}:\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}$.

What does he mean by *"composing with $f$ and $\varphi _p$"*?

Here's the full excerpt:

> [image]

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You start off with a map $\alpha\colon V \to \coprod_{\mathfrak{p} \in V} A_\mathfrak{p}$. You end up with a map $f^{-1}(V) \to \coprod_{\mathfrak{q} \in f^{-1}(V)} B_\mathfrak{q}$ sending $\mathfrak{q}$ to $\varphi_\mathfrak{q}(\alpha(f(\mathfrak{q}))$. It's not quite as simple as precomposing with $f$ and postcomposing with a coproduct of the $\varphi_\mathfrak{q}$ because the indexing is different.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still do not understand. Hartshorne sais that we get a homomorphism of ring $f^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_{SpecA}(V)\to \mathcal{O}_{SpecB}(f^{-1}(V)) $ by the definition of $\mathcal O$, composing with ecc.  Is there a straightforward way to write this composite map?

Comment: It doesn't look so bad to me as written, and I did use the definition and compose some functions.